# I want to checkout into an existing branch but handle it as a new branch

Tags: git, git-merge, git-branch, git-reset

I want to achieve the following graph topology:

```
master: A---B---C
         \     / \
dev:      F---G   H
```

When i checkout to `dev` after merging C, i want H to not be linked to G, but to C. How do i do that?

Comment: When you do `git checkout master`, which commit does your `HEAD` point to?

Comment: Keep in mind you are trying to do this across a merge commit.

Comment: here is one way to have a nice graph view of your repo in a terminal (note: it is also z good input to copy/paste in stackoverflow): `git log --oneline --graph`

Comment: You can add any other options you would pass to git log, for example: `git log [...] master dev`

Comment: @Dai i rephrased the question to make it simpler.

Comment: @MachineLeon Your post does not adequately explain what `H` is exactly (is it a tag? a dangling commit? a commit you want to rebase?)

Comment: @MachineLeon: If you want H to be in same branch than F-G you have to backport C  in dev, otherwise it's not the same branch if the graph is broken. You have erased `git checkout dev && git reset --hard master` but this is a nonsense if the commit is not in the same branch.

Comment: Your graph is not so clear. In git, a branch is nothing more than a (moving) reference to a commit.
Let's say, before the merge commit C, that `master` was at commit B and `dev` branch at commit G.
If you `git merge dev` when you are on branch `master`, then merge commit C is created, `master` pointing at C, but `dev` reference would stay on G, unless explicitely resetted to C.
So, without other actions, next commit on dev would indeed start from G as wanted.